# shouldoverrideurlloading not working for Dynamic HTML

Tags: android, webview

Inside the WebView of my android, an html page loads up a jQuery ListView from server (using ajax post). However the links on the listView are not being captured by the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method in Android.

I implemented the same using static HTML jQuery list and it worked fine but when the list is being loaded from a server it doesn't work. How can i resolve this.